# Open Word Document with WPF without open dialog

Tags: wpf, ms-word

I have the path to a Word document saved in an SQL Database.

I am able to retrieve the path but I cannot work out the best approach to open the Word document from WPF without using the `OpenFileDialog`. I've given up any thoughts of embedding Word in WPF as it has too many gotchas.

I just want to be able to click a button or hyperlink and using the retrieved document path, open Word.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like

```
Process wordProcess = new Process();
wordProcess.StartInfo.FileName = pathToYourDocument;
wordProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
wordProcess.Start();
```

By setting UseShellExecute to true it will open the document using the default program,
in your case Word.